# LibGDX square stretches with resolution

Tags: java, libgdx

I was under the assumption ShapeRenderer.rect draws in pixels but it stretches the square when I stretch the resolution and turns it into a rectangle.

```
        shapeRenderer.identity();
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        shapeRenderer.rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        shapeRenderer.end();
```

Comment: Work with a `Viewport`. For example use a `FitViewport` to keep the aspect ratio. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using Orthographic Camera

If you write

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(constant_Width, constant_Height);
```

That will cause your rectangle to get stretched one method to solve this is to use ratio

```
camera = new Orthographic Camera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth/Ratio, Gdx.graphics.getHeight/Ratio);
```

This should solve your problem.
Enjoy :)

EDIT:

How could I have forgotten this part

after you declare your camera you need to do this

```
camera.translate(Gdx.graphics.getWidth/Ratio/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight/Ratio/2)
```

If you miss that line, you (0, 0) will be at the center of your screen. I assume that you want your (0, 0) to be the bottom left corner of your screen.

Comment: I should use shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined); with your code above right? Can you give me an example of drawing a rectangle and different ratios, Say a regular square but at different ratios how you would handle that.

Comment: yes you should use setProjectionMatrix after what i have told you

Comment: remember my Ratio variable, just change that